# Strange behavior on :hover appearance on Safari browser

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

Yesterday our client reported strange and undesirable bahavior at his website. Website address is: http://dawidbukiel.pl/#offer, section "offer" (Oferta). It should work like this:
[image: a busy cat]
and it does, despite Safari. 
After action

```
#offer > div > div:hover
```

box with offer details (.offerHover) should appear. At Safari, unfortunatelly, it happenes otherwise. Box sometimes appears, sometimes doesn't and sometimes appears with low opacity.
Main problem is - we don't have any mac device, so there is no way to try and fix it. Do you have any clue what might be wrong? I tried testing old Safari version on Windows, but it seems to be working fine.
I would be very grateful for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself.
I dunno why, but it works :D
I just had to get rid of keyframes.

from:

```
.offerHover {
background: rgba(0, 81, 203, 1);
height: 200px;
margin-right: 0px;
}

#offer > div > .col-md-4:hover .offerHover {
-webkit-animation: jumpOut 0.5s forwards;
animation: jumpOut 0.5s forwards;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

to:

```
.offerHover {
background: rgba(0, 81, 203, 1);
height: 200px;
margin-right: 0px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#offer > div > .col-md-4:hover .offerHover {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(15px, 15px, 0);
transform: translate3d(15px, 15px, 0);
opacity: 1;
}
```